# Conditionally add a class to dynamically generated fields

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-class

I'm making some sort of validation using ng-class directive, but there's a problem when starting to deal with ng-repeat created elements.

```
<div class="traveler" ng-repeat="i in getNumber(travelers_count) track by $index" style="margin-top: 15px">
                        <div class="inp-wr wr-traveler">
                            <input
                                ng-class="{ 'has-error' : valError && mainForm.last_name[{{$index + 1}}].$invalid}"
                                required
                                class="text-inp"
                                style="width: 200px"
                                ng-model="$parent.last_name[$index]"
                                ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"
                                ng-pattern="namePattern"
                                name="last_name[{{$index + 1}}]"
                                placeholder = "Last name">
                        </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to make this one work? 
`ng-class="{ 'has-error' : valError && mainForm.last_name[{{$index + 1}}].$invalid}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found quick solution - need to wrap input in `<ng-form>` and check validity of it. I.e

```
<div class="traveler" ng-repeat="i in getNumber(travelers_count) track by $index" style="margin-top: 15px">
                            <div class="inp-wr wr-traveler">
<ng-form name="lastNameForm">
                                <input
                                    ng-class="{ 'has-error' : valError && lastNameForm.$invalid}"
                                    required
                                    class="text-inp"
                                    style="width: 200px"
                                    ng-model="$parent.last_name[$index]"
                                    ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"
                                    ng-pattern="namePattern"
                                    name="last_name[{{$index + 1}}]"
                                    placeholder = "Last name">
</ng-form>
                            </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the brackets.

```
mainForm.last_name[$index + 1].$invalid
```

Comment: After removing brackets firebug assumes $index+1 as a plain text